# Simplifying $\frac{{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}}1+\tan^2\theta_i}{{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}}1+\cot^2\theta_i}$, where $\theta_i = \frac{2^{i-1}\pi}{2^n+1}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

How to simplify this expression?

> $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\tan^2\theta_i\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\cot^2\theta_i\right)}$$
>
> where $$\theta_i = \frac{2^{i-1}\pi}{2^n+1}$$

Comment: what ? how? could you please recheck your calculations?

Comment: seriously, why is this question being downvoted?

Comment: Can you show some of your efforts? This will help us pick up where you left off :)

Comment: i tried with roots of unity. with n=3, formed an equation whose roots are square the given angles, but one angle tan 3pi/9 was also root. but its value was known so i could find. but then not able to generalize for n.

Comment: Getting answer $3....$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\displaystyle \theta_{i}=\frac{2^{i-1}}{2^n+1}$

Using the Identity  $$\sec^2(\theta_{i})=4\csc^2(2\theta_{i})-\csc^2(\theta_{i})$$  and using $\displaystyle \theta_{i+1}=2\theta_{i}.$

and we  have $$\csc^2(\theta_{n+1})=\csc^2(\theta_{1}).$$

$$\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i=1}\sec^2(\theta_{i})=4\sum^{n}_{i=1}\csc^2(\theta_{i+1})-\sum^{n}_{i=1}$$

$$\csc^2(\theta_{i})=3\sum^{n}_{i=1}\csc^2(\theta_{i}).$$